# Removing a Subversion folder from the client and server

Tags: svn, directory

I have been using Subversion for a few days now and have a question...

I have a folder deep in my subversion trunk
that I want to remove and replace with another folder.

I have read about this on here and tried:

- Export:

  - I clicked on the folder I wanted to remove
  - I then created a new backup folder elsewhere when prompted
  - I then exported
- Delete:

  - I next chose the delete option (in TortoiseSVN) on the 
    folder I wanted to remove and clicked it.

The folder I want to remove now has an "X" over it as does 
all of the subfolders and files. But, when I go to the Subversion repository
on the remote server, I still see the folder I want to remove and all of its files.

What do I have to do to get the clients to forget about this folder and the Subversion
server to remove it permanently from its sub-folders?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`commit`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re06.html) your change.

> svn commit — Send changes from your
>   working copy to the repository.

Note, there is no need to export your folder before doing this. Subversion keeps a history of all changes, so if you need to get this data, you can browse previous revisions and you can access the folder.

Comment: Thanks that did it. Yes, I thought the export move was odd but I must have misunderstood what I was reading in another post. Thanks again